# Firebase Data Structure for shared data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing an Android app which uses Firebase realtime database. It's the first time I've used any Firebase products so it's been quite a learning curve so far, with already multiple data structure changes as the app develops and I learn more best practice.

I understand I should [avoid nesting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure) wherever possible so at the moment I have my data stuctured like so;

```
{
  "projects" : {
    "jyZdNutWvUbA4XrQ3Gbb17rByyA2" : {
      "-KcAq7Cx7wQL99_3Jo9l" : {
        "area" : "R",
        "dateCreated" : 1486257427801,
        "dateModified" : 1486257427801,
        "latitude" : 999.9,
        "location" : "R",
        "longitude" : 999.9,
        "weather" : "R"
      },
      "-KcAqACaNOHSELyNfSu4" : {
        "area" : "A",
        "dateCreated" : 1486257440065,
        "dateModified" : 1486257440065,
        "latitude" : 999.9,
        "location" : "A",
        "longitude" : 999.9,
        "weather" : "A"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a `projects` node which will store all the project data, then the unique `userid` child nodes (only 1 user in the above snippet) where each users projects are stored, then the unique `projectid` (2 projects in the above example) and finally all the details of a specific project. The idea being the app will just need to nvaigate to the apllicable `userid` and pull all children from there.

I have since decided I would like to add the ability to share a project with another user. I found [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/zNfXY7fKUI0) (example code below if I implemented in my scenario) which seem's to do pretty much what I want, but I worry it will be less efficient as surely now I will need to scan all projects and dig an additional child deep (assuming I use the exact schema detailed below) before being able to check against rules as to whether a particular user is the owner or is allowed to read/write?

```
{
  "projects" : {    
    "-KcAq7Cx7wQL99_3Jo9l" : {
      "area" : "R",
      "dateCreated" : 1486257427801,
      "dateModified" : 1486257427801,
      "latitude" : 999.9,
      "location" : "R",
      "longitude" : 999.9,
      "weather" : "R",
      "owner" : ""jyZdNutWvUbA4XrQ3Gbb17rByyA2",
      "shares" : {
        "uid" : "true"
      }
    },
    "-KcAqACaNOHSELyNfSu4" : {
      "area" : "A",
      "dateCreated" : 1486257440065,
      "dateModified" : 1486257440065,
      "latitude" : 999.9,
      "location" : "A",
      "longitude" : 999.9,
      "weather" : "A"
      "owner" : ""jyZdNutWvUbA4XrQ3Gbb17rByyA2",
      "shares" : {
        "uid" : "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Additionally, many example data structures I have come across tend to store the data in a similar fashion to the second code snippet, i.e;

`projects/projectid/userid` whereas at the moment I have `projects/userid/projectid` which to me looks more efficient as you don't need to dig into each project to check if you have access to read/write. Am I misunderstanding the concept of how it works with my methodology?

The doubt the app is going to be huge with regards the database so I guess performance won't really be impacted that much regardless of my structure, but I do like to adhere to best practices wherever possible.

Comment: So far you've only shared data structures, which by themselves have no performance characteristics. Data is just data. Can you share a snippet of code that you think won't perform well?

Comment: In general keeping relations in both directions (e.g. keeping the users for each project *and* the projects for each user) is a common approach in NoSQL data modeling. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and viewing [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) to get over the anxiety.